Web page from other server, without changing URL
I have two pages:
mainpage.com and reservepage.com
I would like some content from reservepage to be displayed on mainpage, but I don't want URL to change to reservepage.
I use apache.
Example:
URL:



URL
Content from




mainpage.com
mainpage.com


mainpage.com/product/
reservepage.com/product123


mainpage.com/product/about
mainpage.com/product/about



Here is part of my virtualhost code for mainpage.com:
RewriteEngine On  
        
#Proxy requests for /product to https://reservepage.com/product123/ 
ProxyPass "/product" "https://reservepage.com/product123/" 
ProxyPassReverse "/product" "https://reservepage.com/product123/"  
        
#Exclude specific paths from being proxied 
ProxyPassMatch "^/product/.*" "!"  
        
SSLProxyEngine On

Code works for mainpage.com/product/,
but doesn't work for mainpage.com/product/about.
On mainpage.com/product/about returns 404 error from reservepage.com.

I understand your question such that you do not want any subpath under /product/... to be proxyed, but that you actually only want to proxy the exact request to path /product/.
I would use the rewriting module for that, it allows to easily setup a precisely matching rule:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /?product/$ https://reservepage.com/product123/ [P,L]

This will use the proxy modules as before, but this time integrated into the rewriting module. That allows to use a simple rewrite rule that matches the exact path /product/.
If you want the trailing slash to be optional then that variant should do:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /?product/?$ https://reservepage.com/product123/ [P,L]

These modules need to be installed: mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http, mod_rewrite.
